# Android: how to programmatically check about the app auto-update settings

Tags: java, android, google-play, settings, auto-update

I would like to know if it is possible to programmatically check auto-update settings (Google Play) for an app so it is able to know it will be automatically updated or not.
If yes, how?

Comment: Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449299/how-to-check-if-user-set-manual-update-or-auto-update-in-android https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628897/check-if-auto-update-is-enabled-in-android-system-settings But still no luck so far