# How can I programmatically detect if an app is getting updated automatically?

Tags: android

For Bitcoin wallets, Google Play's auto update is a double-edged sword and in case of an exit scam or disgruntled release manager pushing an evil update, getting many users to update quickly is dangerous. Can I query if any app is set to update automatically in Google Play? If not, can I query if *my* app is set to update automatically?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628897/check-if-auto-update-is-enabled-in-android-system-settings) didn't get an answer in seven years but also a lot changed since then. I could not find other questions asking for how to slow down instead of speed up updates.

Answer (score 0):

you can't check if your or any other app is set to be updated automatically, but you can check from your app side that some update is waiting for this particular app. check out [DOC](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#update_readiness) for more

Comment: I'm still in denial here. There must be a way. If I poke the playstore every night at 4am and the app gets updated while the screen was off ... something like that should give me a solid hint at unsuperwised updates, should it not?